# How to use forloop counter within curly braces in django?

Tags: python, django

I was trying to parse following object in my django template:-

```
obj=[{'abc1',123},{'abc2',234}]
```

I was trying the following code:-

```
 {% for me in obj %}
   {{ me{{forloop.counter}} }}
 {% endfor %}
```

I need to use the forloop counter to get abc1, abc2 values. Its throwing following error:-

**could not parse the remainder: '{{forloop.counter'**

Any help?

Comment: Is `{'abc1',123}` a valid entry as dict? Is it dict type?

Comment: It appears to be a set, but I'm almost certain that's not what OP actually has.

Comment: This is just a sample input i was trying, my actual input is quite huge

Comment: Please take an example from your actual input so we can understand better and also mention exactly what would you like as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not need inner `{{...}}` brackets - Django is parsing variables in outer brackets already.

Also if you need to **concatenate** two values you need to use [add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#add) filter

Then it should be:

```
    {% for me in obj %}
        {{ me|add:forloop.counter }}
    {% endfor %}
```